# Error on uploading one image by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, file-upload

im having trouble in uploading a single file by ajax . here is my code.

**JS file**

```
var _submit = document.getElementById('fileInputBox');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('upload', 'upload'); 
formData.append('SelectedFile', _submit.files[0]);

$('#fileInputBox').on('change', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'upload2.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json' ,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
       $('#sep_s').html(data.msg); 
    }

 });

  // return false;
});
```

**HTML file**

```
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="UploadForm" id="UploadForm">

     <div id="AddFileInputBox">
          <input id="fileInputBox" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" type="file"  name="file"/>
     </div>
  </form>
```

**PHP file**

```
  if(isset($_POST['upload']))
  {
     $ImageName         = $_FILES['file']['name'];
     $ImageSize         = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $TempSrc        = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $ImageType        = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    ..........
```

And the error im getting is

> **Notice**: Undefined index: file in **G:\installed here\upload2.php** on line **16**
>        **Notice**: Undefined index: file in **G:\installed here\upload2.php** on line **17**
>   and so on.

whats is wrong here ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading Image Using JQuery And Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252023/uploading-image-using-jquery-and-django)

Comment: I have looked every post , so dont tell me its duplicated.

Comment: @Machavity There's nothing in that question about the correct way to use `FormData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `SelectedFile` as the parameter in formdata but use `file` in php, e.g

```
$ImageName = $_FILES['SelectedFile']['name'];
```

Also you need to get the file to upload inside the change event handler, that is when the file is actually selected.

```
$('#fileInputBox').on('change', function (e) {
  var _submit = document.getElementById('fileInputBox');
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('upload', 'upload'); 
  formData.append('SelectedFile', _submit.files[0]);
  ...
```

Comment: this also im getting `Undefined index: SelectedFile in ...`

Comment: Waw thanks:) you saved me :) . It works like a charm, i didnt know that i must have them inside change handler . Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can see, is that you attach your image at page-load, not when it actually gets set / changes.

You should put that code in the event handler:

```
$('#fileInputBox').on('change', function () {

  // put this inside the function so that its get set when you assign a value
  var _submit = document.getElementById('fileInputBox');
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('upload', 'upload'); 
  formData.append('SelectedFile', _submit.files[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'upload2.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json' ,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
       $('#sep_s').html(data.msg); 
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: There's probably no need for `e.preventDefault()`. Changing a file input doesn't have any additional default action.

Comment: Thanks , so much , yours also works , +  to rename file to SelectedFile.

Comment: @Barmar You're right, I didn't even notice, just copied the OP's code...